# Route a webpage through nodejs

Tags: node.js

Probably this isn't the right place to ask this but I don't really know how to google it. Let me try to explain:

Let's suppose that I have 20 IP cameras from different manufacturers, each one with its own configuration page.
Also, I have a machine running a nodejs server that serves a webapp (expressjs).
Is it possible to route each one of the configuration pages through nodejs so that when I want to change some setting I access it like 'nodejsIP:port/cam/camid/' instead of 'cameraip:camport/configpage'?

In the case of that being possible, can I do the same thing with video streams from the cameras?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with that video streams, you may find that you'd need to have many ports open (one for each camera) as not all cameras use HTTP as the video transport (instead, they have a specific port that is required to receive the stream of data). Depends on the model. I own a few cameras that do and a few that don't. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

The activity you described is called proxy. That is: You -> Proxy -> Your camera.

You can use Node.js as a proxy, there are quite a huge variety of how you could achieve this, as a an example check out the [Node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) module.

Proxying the video streams might be more difficult, but once you proxy configuration pages, you shall have enough knowledge to start with the second part.